# How to increase the limitation of kudu table column from 300 to 1000?

Tags: kudu

We want to increase the limitation of kudu table column from 300 to 1000.

Please suggest the steps or approach to increase? We know it might affect the production but its client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happens if exceeding 300 columns limit, but here you are: --unlock-unsafe-flags --max-num-columns=1000. this will help you